# Is there a way to add a push and hold to power down function in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, power

I am working with a custom single board computer and am trying to modify how the power button functions. In order for the computer to shut down I'd like it to require the user to push and hold the power button to shut the system down. Currently, when the power button is pressed it shuts off immediately. Unfortunately this cannot be modified in the BIOS. I was wondering if there was a way to add something like this in Windows 10.

Thanks.

Comment: Software no; What you describe requires hardware

Comment: This is done via ACPI signals. Windows 10 has support for these, but your hardware needs to actually send them for it to work. 
On say a raspberry, this can be done using the GPIO pins. But it's still very much hardware related.